# Automatically resize according to the resolution(FLEX)

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flexbuilder, resolution, autoresize

i am developing an application with Adobe Flex in Flex builder 3. my application works fine in 1024 x 768 resolution but it doesn't fit in my laptop's screen which happen to have 1366 x 768. my question is how to make my application automatically resize according to the resolution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do absolute positioning, you create a UI based on precentages and on anchoring to edges, this way, flex will handle resizing for you.

if you use absolute positioning you will need to listen to the Resize event and then start calculating the height, width, x, y of each element.

Comment: Thank you very much !! i overcame my problem using percentages.